# What Google Play Services can I safely disable?

Tags: google-play-services

I need working synchronization and Play Store working, that's all.

What Google Play Services can I safely disable, like AnalyticsService? Maybe there is some description of what certain services do?

Comment: 2021 and I also would like an answer to it. There are clearly processes in the background that serve no purpose but to send google our information and spend our battery. We just need a concise description of the items so we can make a phone-particular decision

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of the services currently destroying my battery (and doing who knows what else !)

I hope someone can expand this list, and add a description, so we know if we can disable each item or not.

- CollectionService
- ExposureMatchingService
- DeviceConnectionWatcherService
- GcmService
- PendingIntentCallbackService
- ContextManagerService
- AuthenticatorService
- ReceiveSurfaceService
- GmsCoreStatsService
- CableAuthenticatorService
- EmergencyPersistentService
- LockScreenService
- SchedulerService
- GoogleLocationService
- GoogleLocationManagerService
- ClearcutDebugDumpService
- LocationPersistenceService
- EastworldService
- DiscoveryService